# Como definir o formato de saída de um XML no PHP?

Tags: php, xml, php-domdocument

Boa tarde!

Estou desenvolvendo um **webservice** na qual não irei divulgar o nome na qual há um método que aceita o XML no seguinte modo:

```
<exemplo>
   <exemplo></exemplo>
   <exemplo></exemplo>
</exemplo>
```

Eu estou criando os XML's por DOMDocument mas não consigo gerar os XML's conforme acima, sempre sai nesse formato os filhos que não têm valores: `<exemplo/>` e isso gera erros no webservice não retornando o que eu preciso.

Há algum modo dessa saída ser gerada por DOM?

Segue como eu crio os filhos.

```
$exemplo = $dom->createElement("exemplo","");
$root->appendChild($exemplo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz da seguinte forma abaixo,  usando a opção de `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` como segundo parâmetro no método `saveXML`:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );

$root = $dom->createElement("root","");

$exemplos = $dom->createElement("exemplo","");

$exemplo1 = $dom->createElement("exemplo","");
$exemplo2 = $dom->createElement("exemplo","");
$exemplo3 = $dom->createElement("exemplo","");

$exemplos->appendChild($exemplo1);
$exemplos->appendChild($exemplo2);
$exemplos->appendChild($exemplo3);

$root->appendChild($exemplos);

echo $dom->saveXML($root, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Output:

```
<root><exemplo><exemplo></exemplo><exemplo></exemplo><exemplo></exemplo></exemplo></root>
```

Exemplo: [exemplo de utilização.](http://ideone.com/DWbaZQ)

Comment: Nossa é tão simples e eu nem sabia! kkkk até eu vou usar essa resposta pra meus problemas!

Comment: E no caso se quiser usar o DOM pra adicionar atributos?

Comment: É só usar o método $dom->createAttribute e depois adicionar um valor para ele, e por fim adicioná-lo no elemento que você quer.

Comment: Tem um exemplo aqui: http://ideone.com/DWbaZQ

Comment: Valeu :) agora sim posso continuar usando XML pra algumas api's

Comment: Excelente, deu certo!!! Muito obrigado!!!